# Showing empty values in join | Sales value - category

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
   cat_tbl.id_cat, 
   cat_tbl.name, 
   Sum(expences.price) AS PriceTotal
FROM cat_tbl
  JOIN  expences ON cat_tbl.id_kat= expences.category

GROUP BY
    cat_tbl.id_cat, 
    cat_tbl.name
```

Result

```
+------+--------------+--------+
| name | PriceTotal   | id_cat |
+------+--------------+--------+
| Cat1 |      1031.40 |      1 |
| Cat2 |       200.88 |      2 |
| Cat4 |        46.44 |      4 |
| Cat5 |       223.76 |      5 |
+------+--------------+--------+
```

The thing is I have more than 4 categories, I tried with different joins but they won't show the categories 1-7 with null values for PriceTotal  .

I really don't know how to make it as such

```
+------+--------------+--------+
| name | PriceTotal   | id_cat |
+------+--------------+--------+
| Cat1 |      1031.40 |      1 |
| Cat2 |       200.88 |      2 |
| Cat3 |         0    |      3 |
| Cat4 |        46.44 |      4 |
| Cat5 |       223.76 |      5 |
| Cat6 |       0      |      6 |
| Cat7 |       0      |      7 |
+------+--------------+--------+
```

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of simple `JOIN`.

Comment: I know, I tried it also but the result isn't changing

Comment: You DO need to use `OUTER JOIN` here, it's not a question of faith or something. After that you need to fix other errors that prevent you from seeing the correct result. Here's the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d71949/3) that shows the simplified case in action.

Comment: For next time, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry will do, but I thought it was very generic one.

Comment: Whether it is or it isn't is completely irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 options for your left join:

```
SELECT
   cat_tbl.id_cat, 
   cat_tbl.name, 
   Sum(expences.price) AS PriceTotal
FROM cat_tbl
  LEFT JOIN  expences 
     ON cat_tbl.id_kat= expences.category
GROUP BY
    cat_tbl.id_cat, 
    cat_tbl.name
```

or:

```
select cat.id_cat, cat.name,
       coalesce(exp.tot, 0) as PriceTotal
from cat_tbl cat
left join
(
select x.category, sum(x.price) as tot
from expences x
group by x.category
) exp
on cat.id_cat = exp.category
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first case be something like `SUM(COALESCE(expences.price, 0))`?

Comment: Lovely second answer ;)

Comment: @johnHC if I wanted to introduce a WHERE statement does it have to be in both places? Like WHERE date Between

Comment: @KavvsonEmpcraft It depends on which table the date applies to. If it applies to both, add to both. Otherwise, if Cat, add to the end of the overall query, if Exp, add into the subquery.

Comment: Oki Thanks, it will apply to the expence

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45732621/introducing-a-new-column-for-previous-month-sum check out, a small modification needed ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT ct.id_cat, ct.name, Sum(ex.price) AS PriceTotal
   FROM cat_tbl ct
   JOIN  expences ex ON ct.id_cat= ex.category
   LEFT JOIN expences ex2 ON (ct.id_cat = ex2.category AND ex.category < ex2.category)
   .....
   WHERE ex2.category IS NULL
```

Comment: Please add some context about why your code should resolve the problem.